# At what point does the kallah take on the husband's minhagim?

Tags: halacha, minhag, marriage

If for exmple a Sefardi woman is marrying an Ashkenazi or vice versa at what point does the kallah take on the husbands minhagim?

Is it as soon they are engaged? When the kiddushin is finalized? Some other time?

Comment: Perhaps after Nissuin?

Comment: As @DoubleAA said, why would you assume that a wife who is marrying into her husband's family would get the customs before they are married?

Comment: There is an issue of where Ashkenazim and Sefardim differ on the marriage process itself. My personal experience is the officiating rabbi aims to be machmir/cover both.