# Niddah customs differences

Tags: halacha, niddah

If a Sephardic/mizrahi man marries an Ashkenazi women, or vice versa, whose niddah custom is followed? From what I understand, Ashkenazim are more stringent on timing than Sephardim/mizrahim, so in the case of “mixed” marriages like this whose customs would be prioritized.

Comment: Not a duplicate per se but the question here is answered in the question there: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/72995/at-what-point-does-the-kallah-take-on-the-husbands-minhagim

Comment: Kirk excellent analysis. In the case covered in that question both opinions are satisfied because the wedding itself must be halachically acceptable to both sides. Once they are married she (theoretically) takes on all of her husband's minhagim, both stringencies and leniencies.

Comment: In practice that doesn't always happen 100%. Also please note that regarding niddah, *some* Sephardim have the minhag to keep one day less per cycle than Ashkenazim but not all, and probably not even the majority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the woman follows her husbands customs so in this case she would be stringent for the Ashkenazic customs.